# C++ templates optimization

Tags: c++, templates, optimization, sizeof, unsigned-integer

At which point will/can the part about the template method be **optimized** by a compiler? Will it **remove unreachable code**, **unwrap unecessary loops**? *(Bits uses **unsigned int** blocks, Integer uses **unsigned long** ones)*

Plus, is there a c++ data type meaning "I'm an integer of the size of your processors registries"?

```
template<size_t bits> class IntegerFactoryImpl : public IntegerFactory<Integer<bits>>{
private:
    template<int sizeOfLong, int sizeOfInt> Integer<bits> getOne(const Bits& b) const{

        Integer<bits> integer = this->getOne();
        size_t roof = (b.blocks() > integer.size()*(sizeOfLong/sizeOfInt))? integer.size()*(sizeOfLong/sizeOfInt) : b.blocks();
        for(size_t i = 0; i < roof; ++i){
            integer.at(i/(sizeOfLong/sizeOfInt)) = 0;
            for(size_t j = 0; j < (sizeOfLong/sizeOfInt); ++j){
                if(i % (sizeOfLong/sizeOfInt) == j){
                    integer.at(i/(sizeOfLong/sizeOfInt)) |= ((unsigned long)b.block(b.blocks()-i-1)) << (sizeOfInt*j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for(size_t i = roof; i < integer.size()*(sizeOfLong/sizeOfInt); ++i){
            if(i % (sizeOfLong/sizeOfInt) == 0){
                integer.at(i/(sizeOfLong/sizeOfInt)) = 0;
            }
        }
        return integer;
    }

public:

    virtual ~IntegerFactoryImpl() throw(){}

    virtual Integer<bits> getOne() const{
        return Integer<bits>();
    }

    virtual Integer<bits> getOne(const Bits& b) const{
        return this->getOne<sizeof(unsigned long)*8, sizeof(unsigned int)*8>(b);
    }
};
```

Will there be a difference with this code (without template method):

```
template<size_t bits> class IntegerFactoryImpl : public IntegerFactory<Integer<bits>>{

public:

    virtual ~IntegerFactoryImpl() throw(){}

    virtual Integer<bits> getOne() const{
        return Integer<bits>();
    }

    virtual Integer<bits> getOne(const Bits& b) const{

        Integer<bits> integer = this->getOne();
        size_t roof = (b.blocks() > integer.size()*((sizeof(unsigned long)/sizeof(unsigned int)))? integer.size()*((sizeof(unsigned long)/sizeof(unsigned int)) : b.blocks();
        for(size_t i = 0; i < roof; ++i){
            integer.at(i/((sizeof(unsigned long)/sizeof(unsigned int))) = 0;
            for(size_t j = 0; j < ((sizeof(unsigned long)/sizeof(unsigned int)); ++j){
                if(i % ((sizeof(unsigned long)/sizeof(unsigned int)) == j){
                    integer.at(i/((sizeof(unsigned long)/sizeof(unsigned int))) |= ((unsigned long)b.block(b.blocks()-i-1)) << ((sizeof(unsigned int)*8)*j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for(size_t i = roof; i < integer.size()*((sizeof(unsigned long)/sizeof(unsigned int)); ++i){
            if(i % ((sizeof(unsigned long)/sizeof(unsigned int)) == 0){
                integer.at(i/((sizeof(unsigned long)/sizeof(unsigned int))) = 0;
            }
        }
        return integer;
    }
};
```

(edit: I just discovered the code doesn't work well (I fixed it) but the original question still applies..)

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve where this is your solution?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582302/are-there-optimized-c-compilers-for-template-use

Comment: Plus, is there a c++ data type meaning "I'm an integer of the size of your processors registries". Hmmm "int" ?

Comment: No, this is what I coded to properly handle 32/64bits compilation outputs, my question is : "Do I have to code every <sizeOfLong,sizeOfInt> pair combination code or will the first solution (above) be as efficient?"

Comment: int is 32 bits on my amd64, am I missing something?

Comment: I actually uses **longs** for the purpose, they are 32bits long min, 64bits on AMD64 so they fit but they aren't exactly "integer of the size of your processors registries", on a 16 proc they would still be 32 min.

Comment: @AurélienOoms - `int` is supposed to be "the natural size" for the target architecture. Ask your compiler vendor what they think that means.

Comment: `int` isn't guaranteed to be the same size as your registers, but in practice it often is the same size as your "regular" registers. Since your 64-bit AMD processor is really just an x86 (32-bit) architecture with a 64-bit extension, it still makes sense for `int` to be 32-bits since you can still consider that to be a "natural" size.

Comment: @GManNickG the problem is to build an Integer instance from a Bits instance where Bits use **uint** blocks while Integer use **ulong**

Comment: @Cornstalks Thanks, I (obviously) didn't know that.

Comment: @Cornstalks Is there any similar guarantee about longs?

Comment: @AurélienOoms: You're missing the point of my question: what for? Think outside the code, what's the real-world issue?

Comment: @AurélienOoms: The only guarantee about `long` is that it's `>= sizeof(int)` and that it can hold at least as much as an `int` can. As far as I know, there's no suggestions made between `long` and any kind of "natural" register size.

Comment: @GManNickG Is it this you want : "**uint** and **ulong** have a platform dependent size, I wan't to cover as much platforms I can."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, the compiler will optimise away things that it can calculate at compile time, and if you have a loop that only iterates once (e.g. `for(i = 0; i < 1; i++)`, it will remove the loop completely.

As to integer sizes, it really depends on what you are trying to achieve if it's better to use `long` or `int`. In x86-64, for example, a 64-bit operation will take an extra byte to indicate that the instruction following is a 64-bit instruction instead of a 32-bit instruction. If the compiler made `int` 64-bits long, the code would become (a little bit) larger, and thus fit less nicely in caches, etc, etc. There is no speed benefit between 16-, 32- or 64-bit operations [for 99% of the operations, multiply and divide being some of the obvious exceptions - the bigger the number, the longer it takes to divide or multiply it (( Actually, the number of bits SET in the number affects the multiply time, and I believe divide as well )) ] in x86-64. Of course, if you are, for example, using the values to perform bitmask operations and such, using `long` will give you 64-bit operations, which take half as many operations to perform the same thing. This is clearly an advantage. So it is "right" to use `long` in this case, even if it adds an extra byte per instruction.

Also bear in mind that very often, `int` is used for "smaller numbers", so for a lot of things the extra size of `int` would simply be wasted, and take up extra data-cache space, etc, etc. So `int` remains 32-bits also to keep the size of large integer arrays and such at a reasonable size.

Comment: So the compiler is supposed to know the sizeof() return value?

Comment: Plus is there a difference between this implementation and one other where I simply replace (see edit above) sizeOfxxx template arguments by (sizeOf(xxx)*8)?

Comment: Yes, the compiler certainly knows what `sizeof` produces. And it knows how to multiply, divide, add and subtract integers (and usually floating point) too.

Comment: Thanks. As for the performances question, Integer<bits> is (indeed) used for multi-precision arithmetics, I can relate for the performance gain of using **ulongs** instead of **uints** on AMD64.

Comment: Yes, obviously, doing half as many operations beats having slightly larger code... The point above is more about the fact that many times when we use `int`, the size of it doesn't need to be more than (or even as much as) 32 bits, and thus making `int` 64-bit everywhere would just waste code and data space for no extra benefit.

Comment: An other question : "Assume my processor was working with 64bit only registries, isn't there an overhead added for using 32bit *or lower* arithmetic (due too masking overflowing bits)?"

Comment: If it's an x86-64, then it will be able to do almost everything in 32 or 64-bit with no difference in speed, or any extra instructions either way. There are a few exceptions, but they can pretty much be ignored. If you are after saving every last clock-cycle, using unsigned for array index will save the odd instruction in some cases.