# Can I declare a template instantiation from a typelist?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-specialization

Pretty sure I know the answer to this already, but it's worth a shot.

So, say I have a typelist:

```
template <typename ...Ts>
struct typelist{};
```

That contains some objects:

```
struct foo{};
struct bar{};
struct quux{};

using objects = typelist<foo, bar, quux>;
```

Now I have a templated class (`baz`) that can take any of these objects. But, due to codebase size and compilation times, I want to have the implementation of my templated method in a cpp file.

So at the bottom of baz.cpp I have:

```
template <> class baz<foo>;
template <> class baz<bar>;
template <> class baz<quux>;
```

The problem is I have lots of classes like `baz`, and the list of objects that they work with is also ever changing. So... is there anyway I can keep my single typelist of objects and use that in the cpp file of each `baz`-like object to specialize? Then, all I have to do is update my typelist when I have a new object and all the object files will rebuild.

Comment: You don't have to *specialize*, only explicitly *instantiate* them.

Comment: This could definitely be done using a macro. Given that this will be isolated from the rest of your codebase, why not just do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `template <> class baz<foo>;` line forward-declares a specialization and not a template instantiation, which, I assume, is what you want.

I don't think there's a direct way to do this, you'll have to do some metaprogramming. You can use [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) to generate all the needed code:

```
#define TYPES (foo)(bar)(quux)

using objects = typelist< BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(TYPES) >;

// Generate extern template declarations in the header
#define EXTERN_TEMPLATE_BAZ(r, data, arg)\
    extern template class baz< arg >;

BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(EXTERN_TEMPLATE_BAZ, _, TYPES)

// Generate template instantiations in the .cpp
#define TEMPLATE_BAZ(r, data, arg)\
    template class baz< arg >;

BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(TEMPLATE_BAZ, _, TYPES)
```

There may be a way to do this without preprocessor but doing this would impose additional requirements on the `baz` type. The point is to use the type in a context where it has to be instantiated, including all its methods.

Comment: Not everyone uses boost and there is no note about boost in the question.

Comment: So? It is a valid solution nonetheless.

Comment: This solution works, but maybe it isn't what the asker wanted. Boost is not a part of standard C++.

Comment: I simply suggested the solution that I think works best - I had solved the similar task this way many times. In case if Boost is not available, there are multiple other answers given. I let the asker decide what suits him best.

Comment: boost totally is fine!

Answer (score 4):

First things first: Correct syntax for explicit class template instantiation is

```
template class baz<foo>;
template class baz<bar>;
template class baz<quux>;
```

not `template <> class baz<foo>` which is explicit class template specialization (forward-declaration).

One possibility could be to instantiate a class that looks like this

```
template <template <typename> class T, typename... Args>
class for_each_class : T<Args>...
{
};

// Instantiate
template class for_each_class<baz, foo, bar, quux>;
```

which would force implicit instantiation of `baz<foo>`, `baz<bar>`, `baz<quux>`. Well, but you want to create this from `typelist`. The `typelist` is a already specialized template and there's no way in C++ to iterate via template parameters in `typelist` from the "outside world of `typelist`".

Another possibility could be to use macro, but even in macro you can't use your original `typelist`. I would conclude your problem hasn't solution with given `typelist`.

As a solution I would leave the template instantiation on the compiler if possible. Unused templates are not instantiated in this case. The slow compilation is due to the way the [meta-programs are specified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/584431/4734434).

Comment: That wouldn't instantiate `baz<foo>`, `baz<bar>`, or `baz<quux>`.

Comment: Because members that are templates are not instantiated.

Comment: @Barry Please read my post again. I'm not telling that this will instantiate `baz<foo>` etc. but I'm explaining why this can't be done without macro.

Comment: Your post says "One possibility could be to instantiate a class that looks like... which would force implicit instantiation of `baz<foo>`, ..."

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this is impossible without using the preprocessor. You may be able to reconstruct the template argument pack from an argument, but you have to actually pass an instance of the argument, which seems sub-optimal. Second, explicit template instantiations are not allowed at block scope (i.e. in a template function), so there is no way to write a template that explicitly instantiates another template.

As Nir indicates, why don't you just use an [X Macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)?

```
#define MY_FOREACH_TYPES(func, ...) \
  func(type1, ##_VA_ARGS__) \
  func(type2, ##_VA_ARGS__) \

#define MY_INSTANTIATE(Type, Class) \
  template <> class Class<Type>;

MY_FOREACH_TYPES(MY_INSTANTIATE, bar)
```

Now just update MY_FOREACH_TYPES when your type list changes.

Comment: Thank a lot for mentioning about X-Macro.  The wiki link is the best!   Do you know what keep people to not use X Macro? (except it is harder to track/debug)

Answer (score 2):

A version to work with an ordinary preprocessor

```
//Header file

#define BAZ_OBJS \
    BAZ_BEGIN   foo \
    BAZ_AND     bar \
    BAZ_AND     quux \
    BAZ_END

#define BAZ_BEGIN
#define BAZ_AND ,
#define BAZ_END 
using objects = typelist<BAZ_OBJS>;
#undef BAZ_BEGIN
#undef BAZ_AND
#undef BAZ_END

#define BAZ_BEGIN BAZ_EXTERN template class baz<
#define BAZ_END >;
#define BAZ_AND BAZ_END BAZ_BEGIN

#ifdef MY_IMPLEMENTATION_CPP  //cpp should define it before including the header file
#define BAZ_EXTERN
#else
#define BAZ_EXTERN extern
#endif

BAZ_OBJS
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick. Eventually with a secialization of typelist with just one (or none) types.

```
template <typename Head, typename ...Tail>
struct typelist{
    typedef baz<Head> head_t;
    typedef typelist<Tail...> tail_t;
};
```

Comment: No, it doesn't instantiate `baz`.

Comment: What if `baz<Head>` was an attribute of `typelist<Head, /*...*/>` ? I am currently unable to test it; the most recent compiler I got is gcc4.3.

Comment: What attribute? I'm not aware of any attributes that perform template instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the existing typelist (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33084314/567292), but are reasonably sure it won't change in length, you can still use Boost.Preprocessor along with Boost.MP11:

```cpp
#define OBJECTS_SIZE 3  // adjust as necessary
static_assert(boost::mp11::mp_size<objects>::value == OBJECTS_SIZE);
#define INSTANTIATE_BAZ(z, N, _) template class baz<boost::mp11::mp_at_c<objects, N>>;
BOOST_PP_REPEAT(OBJECTS_SIZE, INSTANTIATE_BAZ, _)
```

The macro `OBJECTS_SIZE` needs to be adjusted whenever the length of the typelist changes, but hopefully that won't be too often and a modern compiler should be able to tell you what the value should be changed to. You could even generate it in your build system and pass it in on the compiler command line.