# Automatic explicit template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates

I define multiple types in my library:

```
TypeA
TypeB
TypeC
...
```

Users of the library need to write functions templated by these types:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void user_function(
        const T& t);
```

These functions are assumed to only work with the types listed above.

I would like the user to be able to write these functions implementations in a .cpp file without having to explicitly instantiate all types. In particular, because I may add new types in the future.

This is what I would like to avoid:

```cpp
template void user_function<TypeA>(const TypeA&);
template void user_function<TypeB>(const TypeB&);
template void user_function<TypeC>(const TypeC&);
template void user_function<TypeD>(const TypeD&);
...
```

And rather have something like:

```
for Type in AllTypes
template void user_function<Type>(const Type&);
```

with AllTypes defined in my library.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why would your user need explicitly instantiate the templates? What's wrong with implicit template instantiations?

Comment: I have the feeling that `using MyType = std::variant<TypeA,TypeB,TypeC>` could solve your problem. You could only expose the type alias to your users and you can add types later. Your users would have to write non-templated functions that accept `MyType` as argument. But I would need more context on what problem you are trying to solve to be sure.

Comment: @joergbrech for code clarity and compilation time

Comment: Near duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32444256/179910. Looks like at least some of the answers there will do what you want.