# C++ : alternative solution to a template

Tags: templates, c++11

There is a lightweight class that plays the central role in a code. Actually, there are two variants (say, `V0` and `V1`); both have method `do_it()`. This method takes about 10 floating point operations (FPOs) in `V0` and about 20 FPOs in `V1`. This is a small number but `do_it()` is being called all the time and overall these calls take 30% - 70% of execution time.

In my current implementation `V0` and `V1` are template parameters for all other classes that depend on them so the correct variant of `do_it()` is decided at compilation.

The problem is basically *any* class in the code uses `V` or uses a class that uses `V`, so in practice all classes are templates. Over time it becomes a bit annoying and hard to maintain.

What other mechanism of C++ can I use instead of the templates? Can anyone estimate an overhead for this case? Of course I will learn the actual numbers when I rewrite the code, but this is quite an investment

**EDIT**
Let me also provide a (very simplified) example:

Let's say `V0` and `V1` are points in 2D space. `V0` is on a plane and `V1` on a sphere.
`do_it()` is a method that calculates the distance between points and in the case of `V0` is much faster than for `V1`

Then I have classes e.g. `Points<V>` which inherits from a `std::vector<V>`, `RandomWalk<V>` that keeps a reference to `Points<V>`, lots of analysis code like `plot_distribution<V>(Points<V>)` etc.

*Maybe* at some point in the future a user will be allowed to provide their own geometries e.g. a torus. But as for now there are only two geometries allowed and they never appear in the program both at the same time.

Comment: Why is this annoying? Have you put everything in header files?

Comment: Yes, 90% if the code in in *.hh. I don't like it.

Comment: You can move method definitions to cpp files, and explicitly instantiate everything. You only need two  instantiations for each class template, `someclass<V0>` and `someclass<V1>`.

Comment: @tnorgd You know you get [benefits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671383/benefits-of-header-only-libraries) from header-only?

Comment: @n.m would you mind providing more details, how should I implement the solution you propose? Have a look on my edited post: do I just need an explicit  instantiation of every class that now is a template?  E.g. can I move  the whole implementation of ``RandomWalk<V>`` to ``RandomWalk.cc`` and just declare ``RandomWalk<V0>`` and ``RandomWalk<V1>`` there?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you need.

Comment: So finally I decided to use the #define route

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good old macros are still perfectly usable.

```
#define NS NS_ ## VARIANT;

namespace NS 
{
  using Variant = VARIANT;

  class Foo
  {
    Variant* v;
    // etc
  };
  // everything goes here

}
```

Now compile the entire project twice, once with -DVARIANT=V0, once with -DVARIANT=V1. No overhead!

Comment: I agree with the *old*... :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your template parameter will be limited to certain classes (say `V0` and `V1`) then you can move all your template code to *.cpp* files as normal and get it to link as follows...

**Header (.h)**

```
template<class T>
class Foo
{
public:
   void Do();
};
```

**Implementation (.cpp)**

```
template<class T>
void Foo::Do()
{
   ///do stuff...
}

//this creates two entries in the object code for link time resolution of Foo<V0> and Foo<V1> but Foo<anything else> will fail to link
template class Foo<V0>;
template class Foo<V1>;
```