# Include functions from other cpp(hpp) file with main()

Tags: c++, c, function, compilation

I am using C++ for some sequence data analysis, and have found it hard to call functions across files. Say I have a file `A.cpp` with an associated header `A.hpp`. `A.cpp` has a `Main()` function and a function `My_Func()` that I hope to reuse in `B.cpp`, which also has a `Main()` function. My question is, how do I call `My_Func()` from `B.cpp`? I am not allowed to compile `A.cpp` and link it with `B.cpp` since it will create two entry points (two mains) for the program.

The solution I can think of is to implement `My_Func()` in `A.hpp` instead of `A.cpp` and include `A.hpp` in `B.cpp`, i.e. to go [header only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671383/benefits-of-header-only-libraries). But that seems to be very inefficient (though acceptable). I think there should be better solutions, i.e. in python I can just do `from A import My_Func`. I am wondering what would be a canonical way to deal with this issue cleanly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you need additional `shared.cpp` and `shared.hpp` files which will declare and define shared function to be used in (other) various compilation object.

Comment: @AlexLop. Thanks! Seems there are no cleaner solutions. I will go with that then

Comment: note, it's undefined behaviour to have the same function name in two different files, unless `static`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another header file, e.g. `common.hpp` and declare the function definition of `My_Func()` in that header file.

Then, create another cpp file, `common.cpp` and implement the function inside there.

Now, if you include `common.hpp` in both of `A.cpp` and `B.cpp`, calling `My_Func()` will work from both `A.cpp` and `B.cpp`.