# inclusion of header files

Tags: c++, visual-c++, header-files

i have a file named functions.h....now i know that it is not wise to define functions in the header files but that is least of my concern as compared to the problem which cropped up...

i defined a function in a functions.h named

```
 void sayhi()
{
  cout<<"hi";
}
```

now i made a lines.h file whose functions were defined in lines.cpp file...in lines.cpp file i included functions.h...and used sayhi(); in the constructor of lines class...then in mymain.cpp(containing int main) i again included functions.h and in the main i called sayhi();

but when i compiled the program it showed an error in mymain.cpp telling that sayhi() has already been defined in lines.obj...can u point out what am i doing wrong??

Comment: About the wiseness of implementations in headers, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001639/coding-c-without-headers-best-practices and in particular my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001639/coding-c-without-headers-best-practices/1001749#1001749.

Comment: that problem is exactly WHY you should not _define_ (aka. implement) a function in a header file...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the solution is to *declare* the function in functions.h and then *define* it in functions.cpp, the way nature intended.

Comment: @david...okay but i have one more problem....if we declare a template class in header files and define it in the .cpp file and then if we include the header file in the main(containing int main) file then why does a linker error crop up... and the error does not crop up if we included the .cpp file(containing the header file ) in the main file...

Comment: @avinash Ask that as a new question. Comments are not appropriate for asking brand new questions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan...i could but recently stackoverflow rejects a question if it is not upto a certain length as a question not upto its quality....so one line questions cant be asked!!!

Comment: If it's too short just pad it with an HTML comment `<!------------------------------>` or include a code sample. The latter would be better.

Answer (score 3):

Making your function `inline` avoids this multiple definition problem.

Try,

```
inline void sayhi()
{
  cout<<"hi";
}
```

[This](http://blog.copton.net/articles/linker/index.html#inline-functions) link might be helpful to you.

In particular,  it references section 7.1.2 of the ISO C++ standard:

> An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which
>   it is used and shall have exactly the same definition in every case
>   (3.2).

which is why the [one-definition-rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) is circumvented.