# Is there a good way to avoid duplication of method prototypes in C++?

Tags: c++, coding-style, dry

Most C++ class method signatures are duplicated between the declaration normally in a header files and the definition in the source files in the code I have read. I find this repetition undesirable and code written this way suffers from poor locality of reference. For instance, the methods in source files often reference instance variables declared in the header file; you end up having to constantly switch between header files and source files when reading code.

Would anyone recommend a way to avoid doing so? Or, am I mainly going to confuse experienced C++ programmers by not doing things in the usual way?

See also [Question 538255 C++ code in header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583255/c-code-in-header-files) where someone is told that everything should go in the header.

Answer (score 9):

There is an alternative, but the cure is worse than the illness — define all the function bodies in the header, or even inline in the class, like C#. The downsides are that this will bloat compile times significantly, and it'll annoy veteran C++ programmers. It can also get you into some annoying situations of circular dependency that, while solvable, are a nuisance to deal with.

Personally, I just set my IDE to have a vertical split, and put the header file on the right side and the source file on the left.

Comment: Interesting how this answer has been upvoted several times, while cdiggins's similar answer got downvoted.

Comment: Probably because he says it is a good idea and I say it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you're talking about member function *declarations* in a header file and *definitions* in source files?

If you're used to the Java/Python/etc. model, it may well seem redundant.  In fact, if you were so inclined, you could define all functions inline in the class definition (in the header file).  But, you'd definitely be breaking with convention and paying the price of additional coupling and compilation time every time you changed anything minor in the implementation.

C++, Ada, and other languages originally designed for large scale systems kept definitions hidden for a reason--there's no good reason that the users of a class should have to be concerned with its implementation, nor any reason they should have to repeatedly pay to compile it.  Less of an issue nowadays with faster systems, but still relevant for really large systems.  Additionally, TDD, stubbing and other testing strategies are facilitated by the isolation and quicker compilation.

Comment: Yes, I've edited the question text to clarify that I'm talking about the duplication between method declarations and definitions.

Answer (score 4):

Don't break with convention. In the end, you will make a ball of worms that doesn't work very well. Plus, compilers will hate you. C/C++ are setup that way for a reason.

Comment: Yep, that's my gut feeling as well. I'm curious whether anyone will volunteer another view.

Comment: C++'s separation of header and implementation is an archaic relic from the times when compiling relatively simple programs could take a very long time (I once worked on a system that took over 12 hours to build from scratch).  But, that's how it's done, and you should generally use tools the way they are designed to be used.

Answer (score 3):

C++ language supports function overloading, which means that the entire function signature is basically a way to identify a specific function. For this reason, as long as you *declare* and *define* function separately, there's really no redundancy in having to list the parameters again. More precisely, having to list the parameter *types* is not redundant. Parameters names, on the other hand, play no role in this process and you are free to omit them in the declaration (i.e in the header file), although I belive this limits readability.

Answer (score 0):

You "can" get around the problem.  You define an abstract interface class that only contains the pure virtual functions that an outside application will call.  Then in the CPP file you provide the actual class that derives from the interface and contains all the class variables.  You implement as normal now.  The only thing this requires is a way to instantiate the derived implementation class from the interface class.  You could do that by providing a static "Create" function that has its implementation in the CPP file.

ie

```
InterfaceClass* InterfaceClass::Create()
{
     return new ImplementationClass;
}
```

This way you effectively hide the implementation from any outside user.  You can't, however, create the class on the stack only on the heap ... but it does solve your problem AND provides a better layer of abstraction.  In the end though if you aren't prepared to do this you need to stick with what you are doing.