# function prototype without implementation in C++?

Tags: c++, prototype

In the following C++ code he make a prototype then called that function without
function implementation how is that possible and if that a standard technique in C++ could please mention that concept name or refer some other question that answer my ask, I checked weak function concept but found that it did not match what is here.

```cpp
void terminalRegisterCommand(const String& name, void (*call)(Embedis*));

terminalRegisterCommand(F("WIFI.STA"), [](Embedis* e) {
        wifiStartSTA();
    });


terminalRegisterCommand(F("WIFI.AP"), [](Embedis* e) {
        wifiStartAP();
    });
```

Comment: This looks like a *forward declaration*. This will compile, though the function must be defined later on for it to link.

Comment: the problem I did not find any declaration for that prototype so, I supposed I'm miss something in my knowledge of C++.

Comment: A prototype is a declaration. Do you mean something like `void terminalRegisterCommand(const String& name, void (*call)(Embedis*)) { /* some code */ }`. That's a definition.

Comment: yes I mean no definition exist for that prototype.

Comment: Then you won't get a program that you can run.

Comment: the problem it is already running, is it mean there is a definition but I can not reach.

Comment: Maybe it's defined in another source file.

Comment: ok thanks everybody

Comment: It's possible that the function is offered by a library. It's very common to include headers for a library but actually `#include` just inserts the declarations of the header file. So, you could write instead the declaration of a library function directly into the source code which would not make a difference for the compiler. (For the human author, of course, I would not recommend this because it makes the code maintenance more difficult.) FYI: [SO: Is it practical to use Header files without a partner Class/Cpp file in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52646155/7478597)