# How can I compile lsqlite3 for Windows?

Tags: c++, sqlite, cmake, lua

I have a C++ project developed in Ubuntu Linux. This C++ project is not written by me. Also, it runs under Ubuntu without any issues.

I am trying to compile the project under Windows 10 using GCC/G++ compiler and Visual Studio 2019 IDE. I am very close to success.

This project has the following lines in its **CMakeList.txt** file:

```
find_package(sqlite3)
if (SQLITE3_FOUND)
  message("Sqlite3 found")
  include_directories(${SQLite3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE " -DSQLITE3 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG " -DSQLITE3 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
  SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-lsqlite3")
  SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-lsqlite3")
else()
  message("Sqlite3 not found")
endif (SQLITE3_FOUND)
```

I need **lsqlite3**. I found [the source code](https://github.com/slanska/lsqlite3) but failed to compile it using GCC:

```
C:\Users\pc\Downloads\sqlite3\lsqlite3-master\lsqlite3-master>mingw32-make
FIND: Parameter format not correct
FIND: Parameter format not correct
luarocks make

Error: Please specify which rockspec file to use.
luarocks make

Error: Please specify which rockspec file to use.

C:\Users\pc\Downloads\sqlite3\lsqlite3-master\lsqlite3-master>mingw32-make lsqlite3complete-0.9.4-2.rockspec
mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for 'lsqlite3complete-0.9.4-2.rockspec'.

C:\Users\pc\Downloads\sqlite3\lsqlite3-master\lsqlite3-master>
```

The file **lsqlite3.c** contains `#include "lua.h"` and `#include "lauxlib.h"`. It seems that they are from [Lua for Windows](https://github.com/rjpcomputing/luaforwindows/tree/master/files/include) project.

How can I compile **lsqlite3** for Windows and link it to my existing CPP project's port?

Should it be compiled using GCC or Lua?

Comment: "This tells me that, I need lsqlite3" - Eh? For me, "**multiple definition**" error tells anything but missing library. E.g. the line `../bin/libMyLinuxBasedCppProject.a(DataTable.cc.obj):C:\Users\pc\source\repos\MyLinuxBasedCppProject\out\build\Mingw64-Debug/../../../src/utils/string_utils.hh:139: first defined here` tells me that you **define** a (non-inline) **function** in the **header**, which is frown upon: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583255/is-it-a-good-practice-to-place-c-definitions-in-header-files

Comment: `FIND: Parameter format not correct` probably means that the makefile has been written for Linux and use the `find` command. The parameters between `find` on Windows and Linux are different. So, I think the `makefile` you are using is not targeting Win32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are horribly mistaken. The linker flag `-lsqlite3` means "link with `libsqlite3.so`. The correct library to compile is [SQLite3](https://sqlite.org/index.html). If you have trouble compiling it on Windows, there are quite a few questions about it on SO.

Comment: https://github.com/jgranick/sqlite/tree/master/ndll/Android

Comment: In the above link, I see that `lsqlite.so` is an Android-compatible file. I am compiling C++ source code under Windows. So, how can I link it?

Comment: Please just read [the official build Instructions](https://sqlite.org/amalgamation.html) you literally have to build and link a single C file.