# gcc - gdb - pretty print stl

Tags: debugging, function, stl, gdb, g++

I'm currently doing some research on the STL, especially for printing the STL content during debug. I know there are many different approaches.

Like:

- http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport
- or using a shared library to print the content of a container

What I'm currently looking for is, why g++ deletes functions, which are not used for example I have following code and use the compile setting `g++ -g main.cpp -o main.o`.

```
include <vector>
include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(10);
    vec.push_back(20);
    vec.push_back(30);

    return;
}
```

So when I debug this code I will see that I can't use `print vec.front()`. The message I receive is:

```
Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined
```

Therefore I tried to use the setting `-fkeep-inline-functions`, but no changes.

When i use `nm main.o | grep front` I see that there is no line entry for the method `.front()`. Doing the same again but, with an extra `vec.front()` entry within my code I can use `print vec.front()`, and using `nm main.o | grep front` where I see the entry

```
0000000000401834 W _ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE5frontEv
```

Can someone explain me how I can keep all functions within my code without loosing them. I think, that dead functions do not get deleted as long as I don't set optimize settings or do following.

- [How to tell compiler to NOT optimize certain code away?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668103/how-to-tell-compiler-to-not-optimize-certain-code-away)

Why I need it: Current Python implementations use the internal STL implementation to print the content of a container, but it would be much more interesting to use functions which are defined by ISO/IEC 14882. I know it's possible to write a shared library, which can be compiled to your actual code before you debug it, to maintain that you have all STL functions, but who wants to compile an extra lib to its code, before debugging. It would also be interesting to know if there are some advantages and disadvantages of this two approaches (Shared Lib. and Python)?

Comment: There has been an answer given to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7241548/184968."`Partial instantiation`" : `... only the member functions that are used are instantiated. The following is well-formed code:`. I mean than you are asking about "dead function", but std::vector<T>::front() is a member of template. It has not been deleted, it was not even created in your example.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. In the paragaph "**When i use "nm main.o | grep front" etc...**, I tried to say that after using vec.front() within my Code I where able to use the function within gdb. What's exactly a dead function, isn't it a function which is available in my source code but isn't used?? Another question does gdb know about the function .front(), eventhough I didn't use it, but has no debug informations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's exactly a dead function, isn't it a function which is available in my source code but isn't used?

There are two cases to consider:

```
int unused_function() { return 42; }
int main() { return 0; }
```

If you compile above program, the `unused_function` is dead -- never called. However, it would still be present in the final executable (even with optimization [1]).

Now consider this:

```
template <typename T> int unused_function(T*) { return 42; }
int main() { return 0; }
```

In this case, `unused_function` will *not* be present, even when you turn off *all* optimizations.

Why? Because the template is not a "real" function. It's a prototype, from which the compiler can create "real" functions (called "template instantiation") -- one for each type `T`.  Since you've never used `unused_function`, the compiler didn't create any "real" instances of it.

You can request that the compiler explicitly instantiate *all* functions in a given class, with `explicit instantiation request`, like so:

```
#include <vector>
template class std::vector<int>;

int main() { return 0; }
```

Now, even though *none* of the `vector` functions are used, they are *all* instantiated into the final binary.

[1] If you are using the GNU `ld` (or `gold`), you could still get rid of `unused_function` in this case, by compiling with `-ffunction-sections` and linking with `-Wl,--gc-sections`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. Just to repeat, template functions don't get initiated by the gcc, because they are prototypes. Only when the function is used or it gets explicitly initiated it will be available within my executable.

So what we have mentioned until yet is :

- function definition   **int unusedFunc() { return 10; }**
- function prototype    **int protypeFunc();** (just to break it down)

What happens when you inline functions? I always thought, that the function will be inserted within my source code, but now I read, that compilers often decide what to do on their own. (Sounds strange, because their must be rule). It doesn't matter if you use the keyword **inline**, for example.

```
inline int inlineFunc() { return 10; }
```

A friend of mine also told me that he hasn't had access to addresses of functions, although he hasn't used inline. Are there any function types I forgot? He also told me that their should be differences within the object data format.

@edit - forgot:

- nested functions
- function pointers
- overloaded functions