# C++ Dependencies manager

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction, dependencies

We have here a pretty big application that is taking a lot of time to compile and I am looking for a way to reduce this compile time. I thought a good way to do this would be to reduce the dependency between the include files. Do you know any good dependency/Includes manager that would be pretty cheap? Something that would draw me a good graphic and show me where are the "dependencies bottleneck".

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this question could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073384/what-strategies-have-you-used-to-improve-build-times-on-large-projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Source Navigator to analyze the source. Look at the section:
Using the Include Browser in [here](http://sourcenav.sourceforge.net/online-docs/userguide/tutorial.html). Or a better option would be to use [cinclude2dot](http://www.flourish.org/cinclude2dot/)

Answer (score 7):

You can try include graphs in doxygen.

Answer (score 1):

Visualize c/c++ include dependencies with [Include File Dependencies Watcher](http://www.mobile-mir.com/cpp/)