# Decrease clang compile time with precompiled headers

Tags: c++, clang++, precompiled-headers

I am working on a database project that compiles queries (expressed in some higher level language) into c++ code. This code is compiled and executed by the database. That part works perfectly fine.

Right now, I am trying to reduce the compile time for the C++ query code. I was wondering whether I can use precompiled headers to gain performance here.

The query is translated into a file called Query.cpp which includes library/src/Database.hpp. The Database.hpp file includes further files like StandardTypes.hpp and so on. Can I precompile all those header files to speed up the compilation of Query.cpp? If yes, how can I do that? I could not find any good example for precompiled headers so far, only some really basic stuff.

I use the following command to compile Query.cpp:

```
clang++ -fPIC -std=c++11 Query.cpp -I./library/src/ -shared -o libquery.so;
```

Answer (score 3):

to create pre-compiled header include all the headers you don't change into Query.h and use:

```
clang -cc1 Query.h -emit-pch -o Query.h.pch
```

to use the pre-compiled header type:

```
clang -cc1 -include-pch Query.h.pch Query.cpp -shared -o libquery.so;
```

Query.cpp needs to include Query.h

Comment: Good idea, I will give it a try. Is there any chance to see whether clang used the precompiled header or not? What's about the flags: -shared -fPIC -std=c++11?

Comment: Not sure but you can append the **-v** flag which will show verbose output.

Comment: But actually it would also be sufficient to precompile the Database.hpp header, or? It is the only header that is directly included by Query.cpp

Comment: Only one pre-compiled header can be used. you can include any amount of headers into that one header, -std=c++11 is OK, -fPIC is used for shared libraries, and executables, and indicates that executables won't be dependent on fixed startup address.

Comment: I think Also each of the source files need to include precompiled header, the one with *.h extension, not *.h.pch

Comment: I know what the flags mean, but I was wondering whether I have to add them during header compilation?

Comment: No you don't have to add -fPIC for precompiled header since the command will not create executables, std=c++11 is needed only if headers contain C++11 code. but even if it does not it won't hurt.

Comment: The `emit-pch` flag was causing an odd warning on clang-3.8, but it appears to still work if I remove it.

Comment: In recent version of `clang`, it is no longer necessary to use the `-cc1` option to use PCH.  See the question [How do I generate and use precompiled headers with Clang++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55885920/how-do-i-generate-and-use-precompiled-headers-with-clang).