# How do I generate and use precompiled headers with Clang++?

Tags: c++, build, clang, precompile

The [official docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/PCHInternals.html) state how precompiled headers are to be used through the `-cc1` interface, like so to generate them:

```
$ clang -cc1 test.h -emit-pch -o test.h.pch
```

And to use them:

```
$ clang -cc1 -include-pch test.h.pch test.c -o test.s
```

The problem is that the `-cc1` interface is way too low-level to be used by developers from the CLI. In fact, the regular high-level interface ultimately calls into the low-level `-cc1` interface by supplying it with a very large set of arguments that are necessary for its correct operation, for example the include paths appropriate for the compile time system. Without these arguments, the `-cc1` interface has no prayer of working:

```
$ clang++ -cc1 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/stdc++.h -emit-pch -o std.pch
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/stdc++.h:33:10: fatal error: 'cassert' file not found
#include <cassert>
         ^~~~~~~~~
         1 error generated.
```

Is there a way to use precompiled headers from the high-level interface, such that a developer may conveniently tap into this feature during their daily work?

Comment: Worth noting that having definitions in the precompiled header file (which is not recommended anyway) will cause an error in clang++, unlike g++. -- unless there's `#pragma once` in the header file.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why the `clang` docs do not explain this, but indeed as @selbie surmises, it is possible to use Clang precompiled headers (PCH) without using `-cc1`.

To generate a PCH file:

```
$ clang -c -o big-header.hh.pch big-header.hh <other options>
```

This is the normal compile command, except the input file has the `.hh` (C++ header) extension.  `clang` will recognize that means to generate a PCH.  Alternatively, pass `-xc++-header` before the header file name if you do not want to use that extension (or another, like `.H` or `.hpp`, that is unambiguously C++).

You can tell that `big-header.hh.pch` is not object code (despite the `-c` on the command line) because `file` will say it is "data" (at least my version does) rather than object code.  To be extra sure, run `strings big-header.hh.pch | head`.  The first line should be "CPCH" (meaning "Clang PCH").

To use the PCH file:

```
$ clang -c -include-pch big-header.hh.pch <other compile options>
```

The addition of `-include-pch big-header.hh.pch` is the key step that is different compared to `gcc`.  Clang will *not* automatically pick up PCH files just due their name.

The above was tested with Clang+LLVM-14.0.0 on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of your problem is that your filename is `test.h` and clang thinks you are compiling C code, not C++ code. Hence, when you include `<cassert>`, clang doesn't know it should be looking at the C++ include path.  Try naming your file `test.hpp`.  You only have to name the file you want as the precomp header with `.hpp`.  You can keep all your header files with `.h` extensions.

In any case, I might be getting this confused with gcc/g++, but Clang follows the same behavior whenever I compile my code on Mac.  This is how I make use of precompiled headers.  Read on...

If you've got a C++ header file you want to precompile, just compile it as any other .cpp file.  Notice that I'm using `.hpp` as the file extension so the compiler picks it up as a C++ header file.

```
clang -c precomp.hpp
```

This will produce `precomp.hpp.gch`

Now to use the precomp by any other ordinary C++ file, just include the ordinary `.hpp` file:

```
// main.cpp
#include "precomp.hpp"

void func1() {...}
void main() {...}
```

The compiler will automatically use the corresponding .gch file if its present in place of the original .hpp file.

Comment: These instructions are missing `-include-pch` on the command line that uses the PCH file.  Unlike `gcc`, `clang` will not automatically use a PCH file just based on its name.